# Access Conditional Formatting - Fewer VBA Options over user interface?

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010, conditional-formatting

The problem is that while the front-end allows 4 or more conditions, when I tried to set conditions using VBA, I ran into an error when setting the 4th condition.  In other words, if I only tried to set 3 conditions in the code, then the code worked fine.

I am using MS Access 2010.  I need to set conditional formatting for two textboxes on a continuous form.  I know that older versions of MS Access allowed only 3 conditions on a textbox, but I know that I can get more conditions in Access 2010.  My current application has 4 conditions using the user interface.  In my research on this question, one person said that later versions of MS Access allow up to 50 conditions.  I could not confirm this either way, even when I reviewed the Access 2010 specifications page.  But I know I can at least get more than 3 conditions.

Here is the test code that works for up to 3 records:

```
Function fApplyConditionFormatNow()

Dim objFormatConds As FormatCondition
Dim i As Integer 'index number for specific format conditions
Dim stSQL As String 'query to get list of categories
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset

i = 0

'clear out just in case FormatConditions accidentially got saved
'with the form at some point.
Me.ID.FormatConditions.Delete

'get a recordset containing the formatting information
'(ie, get RGB values for each category type)
stSQL = "SELECT * FROM tblTestConditionalFormatting;"
fRunSQL stSQL, rs 'fRunSQL is custom code that gets runs stSQL and returns the recordset

'loop through recordset to get conditional formatting values
Do Until rs.EOF
    'create a condition on textbox named "ID".  The condition will be for
    'the Category/Type (TypeNm) that's up now in the recordset.
    Set objFormatConds = Me.ID.FormatConditions.Add(acExpression, , "[TypeNm] = '" & rs!TypeNm & "'")
    'add formatting for the condition just created.
    With Me.ID.FormatConditions(i)
        .BackColor = RGB(rs!RGB1, rs!RGB2, rs!RGB3)
    End With
    i = i + 1
    rs.MoveNext
Loop

rs.Close
Set rs = Nothing

End Function
```

When 4 records are included in the category table : ie, tblTestConditionalFormatting, I get the following error:
"Runtime error 7966: The format condition you specified is greater than the number of format conditions."

So, there appears to be a bug in that the front-end can handle more than 3 conditions but the VBA object can only handle 3 conditions?  OR maybe I'm doing something wrong.  Has anyone else come across this?  Do you have an idea for a work around?

Thank you!!

Comment: Just my opinion but I think you need to boil down your problem and add the code. That wall of text is not very inviting.

Comment: Yes, please post your code. And yes², the background isn't really necessary to anyone who knows what conditional formatting is.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback.  I removed a lot of text and added the code.  Note: The instructions for posting questions on this site said that we are supposed to list our research before posting.  So, I kept that information in to show that I have tried hard to figure this out on my own, going to some effort above even just searching this site.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `With Me.ID.FormatConditions(i)`, use the `FormatCondition` object that you just created:

```
Set objFormatConds = Me.ID.FormatConditions.Add(acExpression, , "[TypeNm] = '" & rs!TypeNm & "'")
'add formatting for the condition just created.
With objFormatConds 
    .BackColor = RGB(rs!RGB1, rs!RGB2, rs!RGB3)
End With
```

You don't need `i` anymore.

I have similar code that goes (simplified) like this:

```
For i = 1 To 6
    lColor = DLookup("Color", "someTable", "p_Color_ID = " & i)
    Set objFrc = txtFld.FormatConditions.Add(acExpression, , "[ColorGroup] = '" & i & "'")
    objFrc.BackColor = lColor
Next i
```

**Edit**

Apparently you can edit the FormatConditions >= 3 if you don't touch 0..2:
https://access-programmers.co.uk/forums/showthread.php?t=271679

Maybe I have something like this... :/

Comment: Andre:  Thanks so much for getting back to me so quickly and with your very clear answer.  (I should have used the newly created object regardless of this problem.)  The snippet of your own code looks exactly like what I am trying to do.  Unfortunately, even when I modify the code exactly as you showed in the first example, I get the same error I was getting before.  I wouldn't expect the error given that your code works.  Can I ask what version of MS Access you are using?

Comment: That's surprising. I use Access 2010 too. BUT - I just tried it in a new DB, and I get the same error as you. WTF. On Monday I can check the actual DB where I have the running code, to see what is different. --- This may be of interest: http://www.utteraccess.com/forum/index.php?showtopic=2034035 @user6388060

Comment: Andre:  You are awesome!  I can't try this until Monday, but I'm super excited to try the i = 3 (ie, not touching the first three conditions) idea.  This is definitely a bug, but I like that the work around is easy.  FYI: I spent hours searching the web to try to figure this out and I never found the two links you found.  Thank you!  I'll report back on Monday.

Comment: Andre:  I did a lot of code variations before I hit on something that worked.  I don't know which changes are required, but I did get it work using a combination of the i = 3 trick you found *and* manually setting 3 dummy conditions in the user interface.  Of course, then I had to remove my initial statement that had cleared out conditions first thing.  Thanks for your help!  I'll mark your post as the answer (assuming I can figure out how--or do I just up-vote it?).  (If you still wanted to share info on how your actual DB worked, that would be interesting!)