# How to reference textbox name in conditional formatting expression

Tags: vba, ms-access, conditional-formatting

**Background**:
I'm manually creating a crosstab subform with conditional formatting on continuous forms. To dynamically format and hide data fields I'm using conditional formatting. VBA would perhaps be easier but is not a practical solution for formatting continuous forms.

I have 10+ conditions for each column and 50-100 columns.

**Typical Conditional formatting Expressions:**

*Textbox name Role0001*

```
((DLookUp("SkillID","RoleSkillClearView","Role = [forms]![techoverview]![RoleSummary]![Role0001] AND SkillID = [forms]![techoverview]![RoleSummary]![SkillID]"))=[Forms]![techoverview]![RoleSummary]![SkillID] And [Forms]![techoverview]![RoleSummary]![Skill level]<>0)
```

*Textbox name Role0002*

```
((DLookUp("SkillID","RoleSkillClearView","Role = [forms]![techoverview]![RoleSummary]![Role0002] AND SkillID = [forms]![techoverview]![RoleSummary]![SkillID]"))=[Forms]![techoverview]![RoleSummary]![SkillID] And [Forms]![techoverview]![RoleSummary]![Skill level]<>0)
```

*Textbox name RoleXXXX*

```
((DLookUp("SkillID","RoleSkillClearView","Role = [forms]![techoverview]![RoleSummary]![RoleXXXX] AND SkillID = [forms]![techoverview]![RoleSummary]![SkillID]"))=[Forms]![techoverview]![RoleSummary]![SkillID] And [Forms]![techoverview]![RoleSummary]![Skill level]<>0)
```

**Required**:
A conditional format expression that can refer to the textbox name directly.

```
((DLookUp("SkillID","RoleSkillClearView","Role = [forms]![techoverview]![RoleSummary]!["Role" & Right([Me.ActiveControl.Name],4)] AND SkillID = [forms]![techoverview]![RoleSummary]![SkillID]"))=[Forms]![techoverview]![RoleSummary]![SkillID] And [Forms]![techoverview]![RoleSummary]![Skill level]<>0)
```

**Tried**:

1. Me.ActiveControl.Name - Control is not always active just because cf is being applied to it
2. Manually creating all conditions - gave up

Any help would be much appreciated. If you need more info - do ask.

Comment: Why are you looking up the `SkillID`? It is known, since you specify it in the condition. If you want to know if it is there, use `DCount(...)<>0` instead. If the fields you are referring to are on the same form (or subform), then you do not need the `[forms]![techoverview]![RoleSummary]` - part. Just specify the field name (e.g. `[SkillID]`.

Comment: Using ** in code-formatted text does not result in bold emphasis, just shows as text characters and causes confusion.

Comment: your effectively asking several questions without providing enough details for any particular question.  try to find a more precise question that will be helpful.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Thanks for your replies. There are two SkillID's, one from the lookup table and one on the form. I have removed the bold from the code, thanks for pointing that out. The key question here is: "How can I refer to a textbox control name on a form directly from within its own conditional format expression ?"

Comment: Note that you can create Formatconditions in a VBA loop: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41753407/access-conditional-formatting-fewer-vba-options-over-user-interface -- Although I'm not sure if *10+ conditions for each column and 50-100 columns* will leave you with a usable form.